# How do i fetch data from square bracket in java script

Tags: javascript

I am returning a map "preopTrainingMapToDisplay" which contains key string and value as list of class.
I am passing this map to jsp using model attribute.
To access the value of map i have declared an object

```
var mapContent={};
<c:forEach var="contents" items="${preopTrainingMapToDisplay}">
    mapContent['${contents.key}']='${contents.value}';
</c:forEach>

The output i am getting is in the form
mapContent['key'] = [class_name [attr1,attr2...]]
```

i want to access these attr 1 and 2.
How can i achieve this

Comment: `jsp`s are compiled server side.  They will not have access to javascript variables.

Comment: @Taplar then how can i send map from model and access it in js

Comment: Since the data is getting processed and then delivered, i have the format in which i am receiving it after creating obj.. i just want to access it